# Community user profile page view count and last seen date woes

Tags: support, community-user

Two irksome issues I noticed on the [Community user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

- Views count looks way too low - less than a thousand for "user" that exists since the beginning of time?
- Last seen date is `Aug 26 '08 at 0:16` - not sure what it *should* be, but in my opinion such date makes little sense for user that is seen [all over the place](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all).

Any thoughts?

Comment: That may have been the last time he logged in on SO? The bot might be botting on different websites, or its inactive. And what do you mean by this less than a thousand for user?

Comment: @Gabe the bot is eternal, it doesn't need to log in.. as for "less than thousand" I mean the profile page shows 649 views and it's way too low for page that exists for so long - I'm sure more than 649 members have viewed the page by now..

Comment: Oh I see, its not logging in/out so the account is not updating...

Answer (score 2):

Since asking this question I learned that the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) has no real user account or profile.

This means, there's nothing to update, all the details we see in the profile page of this account is manually handled by the dev team.

Edit: as nicael [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118672/community-user-profile-page-view-count-and-last-seen-date-woes/234951?noredirect=1#comment772581_234951), on certain sites like MSO the views count does get updated automatically.

Comment: MSO updates profile views automatically, for example.

Comment: @nicael true, weird. Only a dev can tell what exactly is going on then. On a side note your habit of deleting every question that get downvotes isn't very good in my opinion. Can't force you into anything, just saying.

Comment: Not every. The last was dupe so it is useless.